# Allow push notification popup not displayed

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have developed an app for both Android and IOS to receive push notifications, using phone gap push plugin. when I deploy app on Android device, I'm able to receive push notifications. But when I deploy app on IOS and run app for the first time. I'm not getting the popup "Allow push notification", which will give permission for the app to receive push notification. I want to know if anybody has faced this problem earlier or any ideas to fix this issue. 
I followed several posts online, but couldn't find any thing related to this. As per my understand popup should be displayed by plugin by default.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Objective-C, use below code:

```
//  AppDelegate.m
@import UserNotifications;
```

After that, in method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" add this code:

```
if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    if( optind != nil )
    {
        NSLog( @"registerForPushWithOptions:" );
    }
}
else
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if( !error )
         {

             NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
         }
         else
         {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
         }
     }];
}
```

If you use swift, read this https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/ . I think it helpful for you.

Comment: I'm neither using Swift nor Objective-c, I developed app using IONIC framework. This should work for both IOS and Android.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know about that.